# Hibernate always maps bool isAdmin() to false

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'm working with hibernate and JSF 2.0, trying to set up a web filter using my sqlDB column Admin(BOOL) to determine whether a user can view the administrator settings page, but no matter if the Admin field is set to 1 or 0 in the DB, hibernate sets it to false. Can anyone help me fix this? I used Hibernate's reverse engineering to map the fields to DAOs, but had to do a little fixing up with fields other than Admin. I can include code per request, there's just a lot that I could post at this point, so as not to flood the post, I won't.

Comment: solved the issue, wasn't hibernate, 'twas me.

Comment: Sorry @BalusC, wasn't sure if the issue had to do with hibernate or it inserting values into my JSF beans